# Парсинг JavaScript кода

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста по такому вопросу: для примера:

Я делаю GET запрос с помощью CURL к примеру и получаю HTML, потом я открываю с помощью Хром эту же страницу и смотрю код HTML - этой страницы.

А они не совпадают!

И если я правильно понимаю, то не совпадают по следующей причине:

-Я сделал GET запрос на сервер и сервер мне вернул HTML запрашиваемой страницы. -Хром сделал GET запрос на сервер и сервер вернул Хрому запрашиваемую страницу, НО вот тут и есть разница: Хром по мере получения HTML страницы анализирует ее на предмет JS кода/ скриптов и не лету выполняет его попутно запрашивая дополнительные данные и модифицируя HTML.

И вот вопрос именно к знающим JavaScript, прошу извинить сам я на данный момент JS не знаю, но вопрос такой:

-можно ли как то из JS кода по ключевым словам названия функций - понять, что данная функция говорит браузеру сделать дополнительный запрос на сервер ?
Чтобы я мог распарсить только эти участки JS кода и уже сам сделать все соответствующе запросы.

Comment: Структура страницы может модифицироваться и без запроса на сервер. Короче, вы избрали неправильный путь, т.к. в итоге, в конце этого пути, у вас получится полноценный JS движок. Вам для запросов нужно использовать не CURL, а браузер или его эмулятор. Например Selenium или аналоги

Comment: Возможно Вам вообще не нужна эта страница и эти скрипты, если вдруг окажется что те данные которые Вам нужны идут в ответе на какой-то из запросов при загрузке страницы, если можете то опишите задачу точнее или может даже приложите ссылку на сайт с которым работаете.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, я думал об этом, но мне к сожалению нужно управлять всем эти делом из самого скомпилированного приложения С++ без каких либо внешних для пользователя сторонних решений. А любой "безголовый хром" или селениум - никак не интегрируются в сам код С++, а если и интегрируются, то просто дико сложным способом - после чего еще будут тянуть за собой 100 Мб dll-ки.

Comment: @Daniil Loban, для примера: https://www.finam.ru/quote/moex-akcii/mmk/   - достать данные с графика. Как я не старался понять, но так и не смог отследить, какие браузер шлет запросы в которых он получает нужные данные.

Comment: Напрямую как писал @AntonShchyrov не получится, потребуется что-то типа движка, как минимум если не ошибаюсь для этой задачи может подойдет headless browser погуглите на этот счет, ну и selenuim как вариант - вобщем все что работает больше чем со статикой.

Comment: я посмотрю приведенный сайт

Comment: @Daniil Loban, я смотрел headless browser - но это по сути фреймворк, который весит раз 30 больше самого моего приложения, который тянет за собой тонну dll-ок.

Comment: @Optimus1 именно так. Это плата за полностью рабочий движок JS со всеми особенностями JS

Comment: у меня есть подозрения что данные прилетают через сокеты, но нужно перепроверить еще.

Comment: Бегло посмотрел сайт. Если не ошибаюсь, то ответы там идут аяксом, но зашифрованные. Последний этап там Base64. Внутри какой-то бинарный формат

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, а, чем же они расшифровываются перед отображением на экране ?

Comment: @Daniil Loban, любе взаимодействие по сути по сути идет через сокеты.

Comment: @Optimus1 расшифровываются, конечно же JS кодом, который вам придется проанализировать, чтобы понять алгоритм. Даниил имеет в виду веб-сокеты и сайтом они действительно используются. Но по идее для того, чтобы получать обновления для указанного окна

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, подскажите пожалуйста, а JS движок V8 - тут как нибудь может помочь ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Вполне. _V8 can run standalone, or can be embedded into any C++ application._ Но это чистый движок JS. Т.е. вам придется скачать html страницу, найти в ней нужные куски кода и e;t их запустить в V8